# Enforced memory protection granularity (x86-64)

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, elf

I was experimenting with how Linux allocates and protects memory.

For some of my experiments, I have created a small program in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int gv=10;

int main(){

    char *v=(char*)0x601000;//0x601030
    printf("gv=%p\n", &gv);
    scanf("%s", v);
    printf("You gave=%s\n", v);

}
```

After compilation (partial relro), `readelf -t a.out` returns:

```
There are 30 section headers, starting at offset 0x1a18:

Section Headers:
 [Nr] Name
      Type              Address          Offset            Link
      Size              EntSize          Info              Align
      Flags
 [ 0]
      NULL                   NULL             0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0
      0000000000000000 0000000000000000  0                 0
      [0000000000000000]:
 [ 1] .interp
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000400238  0000000000000238  0
      000000000000001c 0000000000000000  0                 1
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [ 2] .note.ABI-tag
      NOTE                   NOTE             0000000000400254  0000000000000254  0
      0000000000000020 0000000000000000  0                 4
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id
      NOTE                   NOTE             0000000000400274  0000000000000274  0
      0000000000000024 0000000000000000  0                 4
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [ 4] .gnu.hash
      GNU_HASH               GNU_HASH         0000000000400298  0000000000000298  5
      000000000000001c 0000000000000000  0                 8
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [ 5] .dynsym
      DYNSYM                 DYNSYM           00000000004002b8  00000000000002b8  6
      0000000000000078 0000000000000018  1                 8
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [ 6] .dynstr
      STRTAB                 STRTAB           0000000000400330  0000000000000330  0
      0000000000000058 0000000000000000  0                 1
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [ 7] .gnu.version
      VERSYM                 VERSYM           0000000000400388  0000000000000388  5
      000000000000000a 0000000000000002  0                 2
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [ 8] .gnu.version_r
      VERNEED                VERNEED          0000000000400398  0000000000000398  6
      0000000000000030 0000000000000000  1                 8
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [ 9] .rela.dyn
      RELA                   RELA             00000000004003c8  00000000000003c8  5
      0000000000000018 0000000000000018  0                 8
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [10] .rela.plt
      RELA                   RELA             00000000004003e0  00000000000003e0  5
      0000000000000060 0000000000000018  12                8
      [0000000000000042]: ALLOC, INFO LINK
 [11] .init
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000400440  0000000000000440  0
      000000000000001a 0000000000000000  0                 4
      [0000000000000006]: ALLOC, EXEC
 [12] .plt
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000400460  0000000000000460  0
      0000000000000050 0000000000000010  0                 16
      [0000000000000006]: ALLOC, EXEC
 [13] .text
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         00000000004004b0  00000000000004b0  0
      00000000000001b2 0000000000000000  0                 16
      [0000000000000006]: ALLOC, EXEC
 [14] .fini
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000400664  0000000000000664  0
      0000000000000009 0000000000000000  0                 4
      [0000000000000006]: ALLOC, EXEC
 [15] .rodata
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000400670  0000000000000670  0
      0000000000000029 0000000000000000  0                 8
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [16] .eh_frame_hdr
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         000000000040069c  000000000000069c  0
      0000000000000034 0000000000000000  0                 4
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [17] .eh_frame
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         00000000004006d0  00000000000006d0  0
      00000000000000f4 0000000000000000  0                 8
      [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
 [18] .init_array
      INIT_ARRAY             INIT_ARRAY       0000000000600e10  0000000000000e10  0
      0000000000000008 0000000000000000  0                 8
      [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
 [19] .fini_array
      FINI_ARRAY             FINI_ARRAY       0000000000600e18  0000000000000e18  0
      0000000000000008 0000000000000000  0                 8
      [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
 [20] .jcr
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000600e20  0000000000000e20  0
      0000000000000008 0000000000000000  0                 8
      [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
 [21] .dynamic
      DYNAMIC                DYNAMIC          0000000000600e28  0000000000000e28  6
      00000000000001d0 0000000000000010  0                 8
      [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
 [22] .got
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000600ff8  0000000000000ff8  0
      0000000000000008 0000000000000008  0                 8
      [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
 [23] .got.plt
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000601000  0000000000001000  0
      0000000000000038 0000000000000008  0                 8
      [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
 [24] .data
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000601038  0000000000001038  0
      0000000000000008 0000000000000000  0                 4
      [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
 [25] .bss
      NOBITS                 NOBITS           0000000000601040  0000000000001040  0
      0000000000000008 0000000000000000  0                 1
      [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
 [26] .comment
      PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000000000001040  0
      000000000000002d 0000000000000001  0                 1
      [0000000000000030]: MERGE, STRINGS
 [27] .shstrtab
      STRTAB                 STRTAB           0000000000000000  000000000000106d  0
      0000000000000108 0000000000000000  0                 1
      [0000000000000000]:
 [28] .symtab
      SYMTAB                 SYMTAB           0000000000000000  0000000000001178  29
      0000000000000648 0000000000000018  45                8
      [0000000000000000]:
 [29] .strtab
      STRTAB                 STRTAB           0000000000000000  00000000000017c0  0
      0000000000000255 0000000000000000  0                 1
      [0000000000000000]:
```

and the `readelf -l a.out` returns:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x4004b0
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
 Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
 PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
 INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
     [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
 LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                0x00000000000007c4 0x00000000000007c4  R E    200000
 LOAD           0x0000000000000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10
                0x0000000000000230 0x0000000000000238  RW     200000
 DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000e28 0x0000000000600e28 0x0000000000600e28
                0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  RW     8
 NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
 GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000000000000069c 0x000000000040069c 0x000000000040069c
                0x0000000000000034 0x0000000000000034  R      4
 GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
 GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10
                0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  R      1

Section to Segment mapping:
 Segment Sections...
  00
  01     .interp
  02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
  03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
  04     .dynamic
  05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id
  06     .eh_frame_hdr
  07
  08     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

In one instance of the program when run through gdb, /proc/self/maps returned:

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:30f 2262070116                        .../a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 00:30f 2262070116                        .../a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:30f 2262070116                        .../a.out
7ffff7a18000-7ffff7bd0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 137613                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7bd0000-7ffff7dd0000 ---p 001b8000 fd:00 137613                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7dd0000-7ffff7dd4000 r--p 001b8000 fd:00 137613                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7dd4000-7ffff7dd6000 rw-p 001bc000 fd:00 137613                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7dd6000-7ffff7ddb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ddb000-7ffff7dfc000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 137605                     /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7ffff7fbd000-7ffff7fc0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ff7000-7ffff7ffa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00021000 fd:00 137605                     /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 00022000 fd:00 137605                     /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Having that in mind, what I would expect the memory region between 0x601000-0x602000 to be writable. But when I run the program with 24 characters or more, it crashed with `v=0x601000`.

When I changed `v` to 0x6010**20** then the program crashed after I entered 0x1000-**0x20** characters.

How is that behavior explained?  Isn't the memory protection enforced on page granularity?  Here it looks like the memory region between 0x601018-0x601020 is somehow read-only.

I guess the problem is inside the .got.plt section (loaded at 0x601000 with size 0x38) but what is it exactly?

---

Edit:

The output of `ld --verbose | fgrep -A 3 -B 3 -i relro` is:

```
 .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
 .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
 .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
 . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 24 ? 24 : 0, .);
 .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
 .data           :
```

This probably tells us that RELRO has something to do with that, but still, shouldn't the memory be protected in page-size granularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. By filling that region with junk I had overwritten the printf's got entry, which with its final invocation caused the segmentation.

So if we modify the code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gv=10;

int main(){

  char *v=(char*)0x601000;
  printf("gv=%p\n", &gv);
  scanf("%s", v);
  //printf("You gave=%s\n", v);

}
```

there should be no problem with filling v with 0x1000 characters (watch out \0)

The RELRO reference of the first post is unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

`.got.plt` is essential for making library calls (including but not limited to to calls to `libc`).
Once you're done corrupting that section, making any libc calls is off-limits.

If you run the binary through `gdb`, you shouldn't be getting a segfault in `scanf` — you should be getting a segfault in `printf@plt`, as the dynamic call can't be made with a corrupted `.got.plt` section.

You should still be able to make non-dynamic calls and syscalls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  __asm(
    "finish:"
        "mov $60, %rax\n"
        "mov $42, %rdi\n"
        "syscall\n"
     );

int gv=10;

int main(){

  char *v=(char*)0x601000;//0x601030
  printf("gv=%p\n", &gv);
  scanf("%s", v);
  _Noreturn void finish(void);
  finish();
  //should exit with 42

  printf("You gave=%s\n", v);

}
```